# Alarm screen doesn't stay still on Android 23 when screen is locked

Tags: android, alarm

I am working on an Alarm app. It works on Android version > 23. But on Android 23 it has some problems when the screen is locked. The alarm screen appears and suddenly disappears on Android 23 (I wasn't sure how to explain it so I have attached a gif). It also hides the screen lock pattern when trying to unlock the screen

[image]

Code in AlarmActivity

```
 requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN |
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD |
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED |
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN |
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD |
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED |
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O_MR1) {
            setShowWhenLocked(true);
            setTurnScreenOn(true);
            KeyguardManager keyguardManager = (KeyguardManager) getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
            if (keyguardManager != null && keyguardManager.isKeyguardLocked())
                keyguardManager.requestDismissKeyguard(this, null);
        }
```

If I remove the line `WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED` the screen doesn't flash like that, but then it doesn't wake the screen when the alarm rings.

I guess it is a bug in Android 23. is there any solution for this?

Comment: Have you tried without `FLAG_FULLSCREEN`? I wonder if there's some bug there. You could also try adding `FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON`. Also, try changing to `addFlags` instead of `setFlags` in case there is some flag that 23 is expecting to be there.

Comment: Hello Dan, Thank you so much for the comment! I tried all  3 suggestions you provided, but unfortunately, nothing worked. For now I will just remove the `WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED` flag, It has a drawback that, Now it doesn't wake the screen when the alarm rings. but still better than that flashing screen. Thank you:)